# Read vim status line

Tags: vim

Is there a way to read what the user sees in the statusline from a function in my vimrc?

I tried to look the content of &stl, but it contains the "formula" of the statusline I previously set it to, instead of the actual calculated content.

Comment: I don't think you can read directly from it, but you could read the "formula" interpret it, and get the values for yourself. Maybe a little context, what you actually want to do would help.

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

The `screenchar()` function has been introduced after the Vim 7.4 version. It is mainly intended for testing, has has some limitations with non-ASCII characters, but can be used to directly access any location within Vim's user interface. You basically just need to find out the screen line number that the status line you're interested in occupies:

```
:let lnum = screenrow() - 1 " Status line directly above the command-line.
:echo join(map(range(1, winwidth(0)), 'nr2char(screenchar(lnum, v:val))'), '')
```